# Swipe row inlistview to delete like gmail and undo not working in Customlistadapter

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I have created Customlistview and it contains image and some text which is coming from json
I need to implement swipe to delete in a ListView with Undo function as in Gmail App ?
here is my list view screen shot:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at this project:

https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview

Comment: i have used that one but it does not have undo like in gmail ?